# Finding the correct Node version of the external Project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have just received a small `Nuxt VueJS` project. I cloned it from the GitHub. It is probably more than 2 years old. I have different node versions on my computer.

How do I find out in the project which node version is the one the application was built with? Unfortunately there is no GitHub action pipeline in GitHub either. Otherwise I could have looked at which node version it was built with. A Docker Container with the Enviroment is also not avaible. Im using `npm`.

The **package.json** looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "small-project-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.12",
    "postcss": "^8.2.10",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: No magic answer, use `nvm` and try out 16, 14, 12. Until one of them works. Otherwise you can always contact the previous dev if possible. Or maybe check the logs of the last production build.

Comment: The odd versions are not LTS so worth skipping and the exact version is probably not that important either.

Comment: @kissu I using alrady nvm but that not really my question ;-) Is that only this way? Try and error?

Comment: I've answered for the rest too. No magic sauce here.

Comment: Do you have package lock file with you?

Comment: @kissu ok. Then I have to take the version that ejects the least warning.  Thank you :-)!

Comment: Should be taking 5min at max. Next time, help that there will be an `engines` key in the `package.json`. As mentioned above you could also reverse engineer the package installer depending of the Node version but it's more work. And finally, if you have warnings (especially with NPM), you can just ignore them and live a beautiful life it doesn't matter if you app works fine.

Comment: @YJR Yes the lock file is fortunately also included. Why?

Comment: Because lock file is deterministic.Therefore maybe you can find npm version from that may be you can find nodejs version.

Comment: @kissu ok. Pragmatic is always good! How it would looks like with the `engines key i`? I add the node version always to my readme file. You mean i have to put it to the package json?

Comment: @YJR i grep all lines with node but it is a lot. Do you happen to have a keyword I could search for?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json this official documentation have some keywords useful. Example lockfile version.

Comment: Supposing OP is using NPM.

Comment: Thanks YJR! I will take a look! I think in the evening. I i found something i will ping you! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and and try all the versions manually, 10, 12, 14, 16 and 18. You can skip the odd numbers because they are not LTS (and hopefully the guy before you didn't used such).

But anyway, if you don't host your app yourself (means a bare metal VPS), you should just try to make it work with Node 16 because it's the current LTS.

Node 14 being end of life as of today, it's not a viable option anymore. v18 is not fully stable but can work too of course.

The engines key can also be used inside of the `package.json` to give a warning if installing with the wrong node version: https://www.marcusoft.net/2015/03/packagejson-and-engines-and-enginestrict.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In any case, it sounds with your comments that one should approach it in a relaxed way.  It's not really my typical way of development but the project was also left in a bad state. I ask myself: "why me? :-) ". Small note: the current LTS is 18.

Comment: @MaikLowrey the latest is 18, the LTS is 16 tho: https://nodejs.org/en/ I understand that it can be a bit daunting, good luck with that (I know the feeling)!